# React-Bootstrap not working for server-side render React App?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, react-bootstrap

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZEv4mHsU5E) to do a server side render web app but when I attempted to implement React-Router I get the following error

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a 
class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

I have been searching how to solve it but I cant seem to find a solution, any possible input would be awesome.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was in the imports one must need to import as follow

```js
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
```

Also just the standard of loading the  to the bootstrap file